# Writing Pyspark dataframe as parquet by PartitionBy dataframe becomes very slow

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark-pandas

I have a pyspark dataframe which does multiple groupby, pivot kind of transformations and when I get a final dataframe after applying all mentioned transformations. Writing back the df as parquet by doing the partitioning

This take close to 1.67 hours for execution
no. of node * no. of cores per node * 1 = 10 * 32 * 1

`df.repartition(320)`

`df.write.partitionBy('year').mode('overwrite').parquet.path(PATH)`

Also, I tried removing the *repartition* as well even then it takes more or less the same time.

Comment: Could you add the entire code snippet rather than couple of LOC. Also whats the cluster configuration, any executor tuning done, input data size etc?

Comment: @RohitAnil
Assume ```df = dft.join(df2)``` then ```interim_df = df.groupBy("col")``` again ```final_df = df.join(interim_df)``` and then at the end doing this 
```df.write.partitionBy('year').mode('overwrite').parquet.path(PATH)```

Comment: df = df.repartition(320, "year")

Comment: I see that you are grouping df by a column but with no aggregation function. And then joining the output with the same df that you have used for the grouping. Im kind of confused as to why this is being done.

Comment: @parisni it didnt help..

Comment: @RohitAnil I am doing i groupby with Agg.. Can I use window function?

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to achieve here. If you could reframe your question with some dummy data, the code you have written and what you are trying to achieve, its easier to help

Answer (score 0):

Some of the suggestions would be

1. Use persist/ cache on the dataframe thats being used at multiple places. Based on the comment, df can be persisted/ cached.
2. See if the join key is skewed. If it is, use salted key for joining. Consider broadcasting if the one of the dataframes is smaller.
3. Instead of using the default executor configuration, try executor tuning such as number of cores per executor, executor instances, executor memory, shuffle partitions etc.
4. Use coalesce instead of repartition as this would avoid shuffles.
5. Based on the size of data, choose a cluster size and instance type and perform executor tuning based on that.
6. Check if the input data is just a single file that is compressed. If yes, that can also cause a bottleneck.